# Permacookie Vectors

Tags: web, cookies

I'm looking for a list of the various ways that websites can create "permacookies".

I remember seeing a website sometime probably late 2010 which enumerated about a dozen different methods websites could possibly exploit to store data on your PC and later read it back without your permission.  (One of these involved using HTML5 features designed to (I think) allow textures to be cached to store some data as a texture, and then read it back later as needed).

However, given the recent [KISSMetrics news](http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2011/07/undeletable-cookie/), I'm unable to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) by Samy Kamkar.